# Unable to get line number on press of ENTER

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext, on press of ENTER key i want to call a function and go to next line, and i want to have the line number of my current line after pressing enter.

I am using `edittext.onKeyListner`

```
 scene.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                  // Perform action on key press

                String s = scene.getText().toString();
                s= s + "\n";
                scene.setText(s);
                final int lineno = getCurrentCursorLine(scene);
                //Log.v("lineno" , Integer.toString(lineno));

                  return true;
                }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

And i am trying to get line number using this function

```
public int getCurrentCursorLine(EditText editText)
{    
    int selectionStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(editText.getText());
    Layout layout = editText.getLayout();

    if (!(selectionStart == -1)) {
        return layout.getLineForOffset(selectionStart);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The problem is, if i do not call edittext.onKeyListner, then it will give the right line number but if i call edittext.onKeyListner it will return exception
please help

here is my logcat

```
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.example.screenwritter.Newscene.getCurrentCursorLine(Newscene.java:150)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.example.screenwritter.Newscene$2.onKey(Newscene.java:126)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:5558)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1349)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1349)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1349)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1349)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1884)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1366)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2324)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1811)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3331)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2601)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
10-28 13:29:22.997: E/AndroidRuntime(20220):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to go to the new line and i want to call a function on press of ENTER, but when i call onKeyListner, it will just call the function but does not let me go to the new line

Comment: what is that exception ? can you post logcat error ?

Comment: A few things I see at first look: (1) I'd expected that you implement the `TextWatcher` interface and register that with `EditText.addTextChangedListener`. (2) You're using `Selection` to get the text, right? `Selection` gives you the text, that is currently selected not what is content of the `EditText`

Comment: @ jboi then what do you recommend me to use instead of selection?

Comment: i am using a text watcher, let me add it here to, i am kind of implementing text editor type thing actual, see this link for my code of textwatcher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19630187/how-can-i-detect-enter-pressed-without-using-onkeylistner

Comment: Try to return true from onKey() function, I think it will resolve the issue as mentioned above.

Comment: @ khawar raza, return true does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Selection` and watching singel keys I would use a `TextWatcher`. Here's a code snippet to add to `onCreate` for a multi line `EditText` (I gave the id "edit").

```
    ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int lines = (s.length() > 0)? 1:0;
            for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
                if(s.charAt(i) == '\n') lines++;
            Log.d("TEST", "lines now: " + lines);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
```

It logs the current numbe of lines to logcat. You can be more swofisticated with the newline detection, but to show how to implement it, this should be ok.