# How can i detect ENTER pressed without using OnkeyListner

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am having a problem with the on key listener, which i have completely explained here [Unable to get line number on press of ENTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629778/unable-to-get-line-number-on-press-of-enter)

Now if i am using a textwatcher to implement certain functionalities on my edittext, i need the line number everytime when my cursor moves to the next line. i want to know when the ENTER key is pressed, how can i do that

here is the code of textwatcher

```
  scene.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {          
             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                                   
                    //here is your code
                strcheck = s.toString().substring((s.length()-1),s.length());

                if (nowUpper)
                     strcheck = strcheck.toUpperCase();
                 else if (nowLower)
                     strcheck = strcheck.toLowerCase();

             }                       
             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                     int after) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
             }                       
             @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (nowUpper){ 

                if(ix==1)
                 {
                    if(strcheck=="\n")
                        strcheck="a";
                        Log.v(strcheck, strcheck);
                     ix=0;
                     scene.setText(scene.getText().toString().substring(0,scene.length()-1) + strcheck);
                     scene.setSelection(scene.getText().length());


                 }
                 else
                 {
                 ix=1;
                 }
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                }
             }
         });
```

Comment: Your solution isn't to find alternatives to an `OnKeyListener`. You need to figure out why you're getting a NPE. Note that the logcat tells you exactly what's null, you just have to figure out why you thought it wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

try this TextWatcher:

```
TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        checkForNewLine(s, start, count, "new line entered");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        checkForNewLine(s, start, count, "new line deleted");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    private void checkForNewLine(CharSequence s, int start, int count, String msg) { 
        int end = start + count;
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '\n') {
                Log.d(TAG, msg);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `OnKeyListener` for your `EditText`:

```
myEdit.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP
                    && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

                int currentLine = getCurrentLine(myEdit);
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

private int getCurrentLine(EditText editText) {
    int lineNumber = 0;
    String text = editText.getText().toString()
            .substring(0, editText.getSelectionStart());

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        if (String.valueOf(text.charAt(i)).equalsIgnoreCase("\n")) {
            lineNumber++;
        }
    }

    return lineNumber;
}
```

Comment: what is this line doing int start = myEdit.getSelectionStart(); please explain

Comment: It is the cursor position, for line count you can call myEdit.getLineCount()

Comment: I updated my answer, that should give you huge hint, you can modify the getCurrentLine if you want it to return 0 for first line, not 1